# Magento 2 What is the Best way to add the Sales Order view products table to a new tab?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, adminhtml

What is the easiest way to add the Sales Order view products table to a new tab? I have the new tab functioning. But can't figure out how to add the Order View Items table to the tab.

Here is the pic of the table for reference:-
[image]

Here is my sales_order_view.xml layout file:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>          
        <referenceContainer name="left">

            <referenceBlock name="sales_order_tabs">

                <block class="TeamDane\WdOrder\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Tab\EkeyOrder" name="wdorder_ekeyorder"/>

                <action method="addTabAfter">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">wdorder_ekeyorder_tab</argument>
                    <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">wdorder_ekeyorder</argument>
                    <argument name="after" xsi:type="string">order_invoices</argument>
                </action>

            </referenceBlock>

        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Thanks.